# Firefox or Opera extension to save source file

Tags: windows, web-browser

I'm looking for a Firefox (or Opera) extension that changes the behaviour of Firefox (or Opera) when dragging links to files to Windows Explorer (or a similar program).

Let's explain it with a screenshot *(this is just an example)*

This is the current behaviour:
[image: current]

This is the desired behaviour:
[image: desired]

*(when I drag files in the same way from Opera to Windows Explorer, they get saved as `.webm` files)*

I don't want to right-click, "Save link as..." and manually browse to the desired destination every time, which is time consuming and contra-productive.

Is there an extension that can do this?

Comment: Related article: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2457437

Answer (score 1):

[DragIt (formerly Drag de Go)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dragit-formerly-drag-de-go/) saves text and images to **preconfigured folders** (and not exactly in the same way that you want).

> **How does it work?**
>   Just grab an object and drag it up, down, left or right and run the assigned action. Text selections, links, images, addons and extern objects have there own respective set of configurable actions.

Comment: Hmm, interesting extension. [Save File to](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/save-file-to/) does the same thing, but isn't as advanced. And both aren't exactly what I wanted, indeed... - and you might want to expand your answer a bit -|- [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality)

Comment: No problem, here to help!